# Import other application as child and configure routerLinks with a prefix

Tags: angular, angular-router

In our app we have an application and multiple projects. Each project has to be built out on it's own potentially but also included in a larger project. So our structure looks like this:

```
src/app/
projects/app1/src/app/
projects/app2/src/app/
```

We were able to get the apps to load by having `src/app/` routing look like this:

```
  {
    path: "app1",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../projects/app1/src/app/app.module").then(
        module => module.SharedAppModule
      )
  }
```

Then in the module for that app:

```
const declarations = [AppComponent, View1Component, View2Component, NavComponent ];
const providers = [];
const bootstrap = [AppComponent];

@NgModule({
  declarations,
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers,
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

@NgModule({
  declarations,
  imports: [SharedAppRoutingModule],
  providers,
  bootstrap
})
export class SharedAppModule {}
```

And in it's router configuration:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SharedAppRoutingModule {}
```

We didn't figure out any other way to have the sub app import into the first one, be lazy loaded and also be able to serve itself without doing this method. Errors like BrowserModule being imported twice etc... were plaguing us. We tried to follow: https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527 but it did not work for lazy loading (which is also mentioned in the comments).

In our app1 we have a component with this html:

```
<a routerLink="/one">One</a> |
<a routerLink="/two">Two</a>
```

Which works great for when we build out the app in isolation, but in our main app these links will be under `/app1/one` and `/app1/two`. Since we don't want to affect the sub app by pivoting off if it's being imported somewhere else (We don't like that we have to ngModules/routers for it...) we're kind of at a loss on where to go from here.

We tried looking into if when configuring a child route there was an option to prefix all routes within it with something like `/app1` which would solve our issues but weren't able to find anything in the docs or online.

I have created a github repo with what we have so far: https://github.com/MathewBerg/multiple-app

You can run both projects with these commands:

```
ng serve --open
ng serve --project app1 --open --port 4201
```

Comment: You are facing this problem in development phase or in prod phase?

Comment: Development. Haven't tried to build for prod yet :)

Comment: You have not pushed `.css` files in github repo.

Comment: Sorry about that, not sure why they weren't there. Check now.

Comment: I got it now. I am able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just tried building for prod and it doesn't look like this will work, I may need two separate module files.

Comment: I tried this, and i think there is nothing you can do with this. As this will be considered as a single project it will always look for `host/one` route, rather than `host/app1/one` route. You can encapsulate all the routes in one route say `app1` and can add `one` and `two` as child rourtes. This wont be answer but this will work and you wont have to make ton of changes.

Comment: Thanks for looking, we may pivot and not have any routes in the sub applications as that may actually be a requirement.